# How Can I Only Allow Text Entry at Start of Input Field, and Always Append Text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I previously had a requirement to always prepend (to put at the beginning) some static text to whatever was entered in a text input field, and to never allow that static text to be deleted.  I found a solution that works really well.

Not my requirement has changed, and I need to append (to put at the end) some static text, to whatever is entered in a text box.  I'd like the static text to be displayed in the text box at all times, and for any text entered to be placed before the static text.  Ideally, the cursor would automatically be placed at "position zero" in the text input whenever a user clicks on the input, or tabs into it.

Here's a Fiddle that shows first the working example of the text being prepended, and then the non-working example of the appending:

https://jsfiddle.net/dsdavis/x9d36veu/25/

When one starts typing in the second example, you'll see that only the last character typed is displaying at the beginning of the box.

A slight difference between how I implemented them that is worth pointing out, is that in the working example, I use the "indexOf":

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#prepend').keyup(function(e) {
  if (this.value.length < 16) {
    this.value = 'Student Worker - ';
  } else if (this.value.indexOf('Student Worker - ') !== 0) {
    this.value = 'Student Worker - ' + String.fromCharCode(e.which);
  }
});
});
```

and in the non-working example, I use "lastIndexOf":

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#append').keyup(function(e) {
  if (this.value.length < 17) {
    this.value = ' - Student Worker';
  } else if (this.value.lastIndexOf(' - Student Worker') !== 17) {
    this.value = String.fromCharCode(e.which) + ' - Student Worker';
  }
});
});
```

Maybe using "lastIndexOf" is totally wrong, but it seemed like the right way to go.

Can anyone help me come up with a way to do this?  To always display the static text " - Student Worker" in the text box, and to put any text that is entered before that static text?

Thank you!

```
   Doug
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another approach entirely:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#append').on("input", function(e) {
     var s = this.value.replace(" - Student Worker", "");
     this.value = s + " - Student Worker";
  });
});
```

Comment: This is PERFECT!!!!  Thank you SO very much!!!!   I should have known another Davis would come through for me!  ;-)

Comment: So, dandavis, this solution is great, as I mentioned, but I do see a couple things that I'm wondering if you have an idea how to fix.  The first is that I can click in the middle of the static text (the " - Student Worker") and start typing there, and it doesn't append properly.  Second, if I hit the Backspace key at any time when in that text entry field, it causes " - Student Worker" to appear for every press of the Backspace.  Any ideas on how to address these problems?  Here's a video showing the issue:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aq5-uzb0HwGEyPRTq8181DyhAwSsV5CT/view?usp=sharing